# Are you able to salute your Mother Base troops?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Are you able to do anything other than beat up and or tranquilize your troops while on mother base?  Some of my troops ask me to train with them but it seems like all I am able to do is attack them.  Additionally, whenever I **do** attack them, they thank me for it and I can't tell if they're being sarcastic or not.  As a follow up, am I able to pet my puppy while on base?  I feel kind of bad about not interacting with it while it is barking at me.

Comment: I don't know about saluting, but beating them up is definitely something they like. Their dialogue lines suggest they like sparring with Big Boss, and it seems to icrease staff morale.

Comment: @kviiri Technically, you only need to walk near them to get the staff morale bonus.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yuh, I've noticed, but you seem to get a separate bonus from beat-ups as well. Or maybe it was just a coincidence when I noticed if (perhaps another staff member walked by or something)

Comment: @kviiri I just wish they'd fight back at least a little

Comment: Not a direct answer to my question, but once you are able to take DD on missions, you can pet him while he is with you on Mother Base.

Comment: @zero298 MGS isn't a franchise that's supposed to be taken completely seriously, even considering much of the plot's subject matter. The troops are happy to train with Big Boss because he's supposed to be the most badass man on the planet. The reason they "don't fight back" is because of both the aforementioned reason and also CQC is supposed to be the most effective martial art in existence, having been created by The Boss herself. The idea is that they don't get a chance to fight back because they're scrubs so it doesn't make a difference to Big Boss or you as the player when you throw them.

Comment: See also: the "whoosh" jet noise at the end of CQC combos and Million Dollar Man "activate" noise during the bionic arm clothesline punch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your title - No. I've heard a theory that the reason Big Boss doesn't salute back is because the last person he saluted was The Boss (maybe also why he refuses to salute in the ending cinematic of MGS3)

For the other parts of your question, Punching and tranqing them is all you can do with them - Them thanking you is sincere, it's sparring with them essentially.

And finally, petting DD is something I believe that can only be done out on the field.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer: You can pet D-Dog, but only after he is fully grown, and only if he is currently accompanying you.

LoboDemon's answer is otherwise correct - you cannot salute the troops.